# How can I save an excel to R in order to send the code to another person?

Tags: r, excel, dataframe

I have to upload my R-script to a platform. However, the other person cannot run the code without the excel documents which I've "read" in my code.

Is there a possibility to save all excels to this code as dataframes without changing the code?

I've tried to use the `save()` function, however nothing worked then.

Comment: Yes, read in the Excel documents as data frames, then use `dput` to create code that will reproduce the data frames as R code.

Comment: `save()` requires a list of objects as well as a `file=` argument, specifying `save()` by itself should fail. There are several ways to provide data to colleagues. Assuming they are using R, the simplest is likely either `save(objA, objB, objC, file = "objects.rda")` and send that file to them. Alternatively, one can `saveRDS(objA, "objA.rds")` (etc for the other objects into individual files) and then send all three files; there is barely a difference in doing it this way. If cross-platform data-sharing is useful, perhaps `duckdb`, `sqlite`, or `parquet` files could be useful.

Comment: You could also read the excel and keep them as tibbles. Then you could use save.image and store all the data as a rData file.